# nuget sign command fails with NU3018 on mac

Tags: macos, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to sign a nuget package on macos and getting this as my result.

```
% nuget sign MyPackage.4.0.0.nupkg -Timestamper http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp -CertificatePath MyCompanyCert.crt                                                                                    


Signing package(s) with certificate:
  Subject Name: CN=Company Inc., O=Company Inc., OID.2.5.4.18=53202, STREET="123 E Fake St", L=Milwaukee, S=Wisconsin, OID.2.5.4.17=53202, C=US
  SHA1 hash: BED15D4C7E4C3116FAACA5586E5085F6B4BC46A6
  SHA256 hash: 90E979450508F91B44B4D26428B869392AFEDFD45A211E86CE2394274CDFDAD2
  Issued by: CN=Sectigo RSA Code Signing CA, O=Sectigo Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Valid from: 2/11/2019 6:00:00 PM to 2/11/2021 5:59:59 PM

Timestamping package(s) with:
http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp
NU3018: PartialChain
WARNING: NU3018: RevocationStatusUnknown
WARNING: NU3018: OfflineRevocation
NU3018: Certificate chain validation failed.
```

I generated MyCompanyCert.crt from a p12 file I have. What is this error message trying to tell me?

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8593

Answer (score -1):

Did you import root certificate to the store? Here are the steps to import the root certificate.

1. Start > Run > MMC > Enter
2. File > Add/Remove Snap-in
3. Certificates > Add > Computer account > Next > Local computer > Finish > OK
4. Expand Certificates (Local Computer), expand Trusted Root Certification Authorities
5. Right-click Certificates > All tasks > Import
6. Next > Browse > navigate to and select **PATH TO CERTIFICATE** > Open > Next > Next > Finish > OK

The above steps are sourced from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/josrod/partialchain-a-certificate-chain-could-not-be-built-to-a-trusted-root-authority) blog

Comment: Need this but for a Mac:)

Comment: Some helpful links https://ss64.com/osx/security-cert.html, https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/adding-new-trusted-root-certificates-to-system-keychain/. Once the certificate is imported, then run the sign command again.